# Sub-sorting without losing original sort order?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a bunch of files in a folder with a common naming structure that looks something like this:

```
FOOBAR_1A.8_Alice.pdf
FOOBAR_1A.9_Bob.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.10_Foo.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.11_Bar.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.12_Jack.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.1_Jill.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.2_John.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.3_Mary.pdf
```

To achieve the above sort order, I have a first sort iteration that looks like this:

`find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -print | cut -d'/' -f2 | sort`

***But*** as you can see, 10/11/12 is printed before 1/2/3.

I tried piping back into sort again:

`find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -print | cut -d'/' -f2 | sort | sort -t '.' -k 2n`

***But*** this messes up the prior sorting efforts and prints output that looks like:

```
FOOBAR_1A.7_Alice.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.7_Bob.pdf
FOOBAR_2A.7_John.pdf
FOOBAR_2B.7_Mary.pdf
FOOBAR_2C.7_Foo.pdf
FOOBAR_1A.8_Bar.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.8_Jack.pdf
FOOBAR_2A.8_Jill.pdf
```

So, to summarise, my desired sorting output is :

1. `FOOBAR_NA.N` should be sorted numerically for the first character (i.e. `FOOBAR_1` then `FOOBAR_2` etc.)
2. `FOOBAR_NA.N` should then be sorted alphabetically by the second character (i.e. `FOOBAR_1A` then `FOOBAR_1B` etc.)
3. `FOOBAR_NA.N` should finally be sorted by the number after the first dot (i.e. `FOOBAR_1A.1` then `FOOBAR_1A.2` etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `-V` (sort by version):

```
find . -name '*.pdf' | cut -d'/' -f2 | sort -t _ -k2V

FOOBAR_1A.8_Alice.pdf
FOOBAR_1A.9_Bob.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.1_Jill.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.2_John.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.3_Mary.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.10_Foo.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.11_Bar.pdf
FOOBAR_1B.12_Jack.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ok too with dir or ls

```
dir -1v *.pdf
```

or

```
ls -1v *.pdf
```

Comment: Nice ! Good idea and nice and short !  But assumes GNU dir/ls with `-v natural sort of (version) numbers within text`.  BSD is `-v Force unedited printing of non-graphic characters; this is the default when output is not to a terminal.`.  So the longer cut/sort version is more "portable".   I'll still give you a +1 though ! :)